OpenProtocol returns NULL despite the protocol being returned by ProtocolsPerHandle
I am stuck, and as far as I can see the code is fine.
I get the protocols here
EFI_HANDLE* current_handle = &handle_buffer[current_page];
status = gBS->ProtocolsPerHandle(
    *current_handle,
    &protocol_gui_buffer,
    &guid_count
);

then I try to get a reference to the protocol
if (CompareGuid(protocol_gui_buffer[j], &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid)) {
    AsciiPrint("EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL\n");
    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL* protocol = NULL;
    gBS->OpenProtocol(
        current_handle,
        &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid,
        (VOID**)&protocol,
        image_handle,
        NULL,
        EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL
    );

but protocol is still NULL when the function returns.

Which error code is returned by OpenProtocol?

EFI_SUCCESS. Turns out the error was not dereferencing the current_handle being passed in, so the behavior was undefined. Normally, I'd get a sigsegv, so the undefined behavior alluded me for a bit. Did not help that the undefined behavior resulted in EFI_SUCCESS.
